# Get value from textbox within a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

Using MS VS 2013. SQL Server 2012

I am trying to get a value from a textbox that's within a gridview.

My gridview looks like

[image: GridView]

The VB I am using to add the value from the texbox is

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GrossMaximum", CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("txtGrossMaximum"), TextBox).Text)
```

The asp.net for the Gross Maximum column is

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gross Maximum">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGrossMaximum" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("GrossMaximum")%>' Visible="true" CssClass="assumptions_textbox"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

So if I enter a value of 25 into B5, Grossmaximum and hit and update button the value returns to 0 and the DB doesn't get updated.

If I add the following code in

```
Dim test As Double
test = CType(row.Cells(1).FindControl("txtGrossMaximum"), TextBox).Text
```

Just to see what value is getting picked up from the text box its 0 and not 25.

Comment: Is it possible that your grid is rebinding on postback, before the value is sent?

Comment: possible but the text variable doesn't pick the value up

Comment: sorted, I missed that.  thanks